# Can't play audio (ffpyplayer) on android - buildozer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I wanted to test my simple mp3 player program on android, so I did. However, for some reason I cannot play anything on my phone and every time I try to load an audio file, I just get this:

```
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <audio_file.mp3>
```

And the SoundLoader always returns `None`. I am setting `KIVY_AUDIO` to `ffpyplayer` and I am packing ffpyplayer with my app. Everything works perfectly on desktop but I don't know why it isn't working on android.

Is there a special permission needed to play audio and should it be requested at a specific part of the program? As an example, I only request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and I always request permissions after I import everything, should I do it in the very beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The Python `ffmpeg` interfaces are all just thin wrappers around the `ffmpeg` command-line tool.  You probably don't have an `ffmpeg` command line tool on Android.  You may need to look at a different MP3 library that is self-contained.  `pygame` and `playsound` can handle MP3s.